# Bazel: Reading a file with relative path to package, not workspace

Tags: python, relative-path, bazel

Suppose we have a project like this:

```
project-path
├── root
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── gen
│   │   ├── a2.txt
│   │   └── a.txt
│   └── use.py
└── WORKSPACE
```

And in `use.py`:

```py
f = open("gen/a.txt", "r")
f2 = open("gen/a2.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
print(f2.read())
```

And BUILD:

```
py_binary(
name = "use",
srcs = ["use.py"],
data = ["gen/a.txt", "gen/a2.txt"],
)
```

when I `bazel run root:use`, it errors:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gen/a.txt'
```

It expects paths relative to the *WORKSPACE directory*, not the current package (`root/gen/a.txt` here). But I want to access files relative to each package.

Comment: Read about [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__)

Comment: @stovfl It's not about python, but Bazel. As running `python use.py` works already, but `bazel run :use`.

Comment: You don't want to change anything within `use.py`?

Comment: What does your BUILD file look like?

Comment: @stovfl No I don't. It seems a *build* issue. As I said `python use.py` works, and I'm just trying to build and pack it with Bazel.

Comment: @Jin Question updated

Comment: @EmranBatmanGhelich: Running `python use.py` from `WORKSPACE` will not work! Error: Can't find `use.py`. So, compare `python` with `bazel` you have to use the same environment.

Comment: @stovfl You're right. But, there should be a way to access files in a package-relative manner. Sub-projects aren't necessarily aware of the whole project structure.

Comment: @EmranBatmanGhelich: ***"should a way to access by relative manner"***: One option is using `__file__`, another is to force `Bazel` to change the **CurrentWorkingDirectory** to `root` before starting `use.py`.

Comment: @stovfl Would you please, tell how to  force Bazel to change the CurrentWorkingDirectory?

Comment: @EmranBatmanGhelich: ***"tell how to force Bazel to change the CWD"**: I would have done, if i know

Answer (score 0):

Add Skylib to your project, i.e. extend you WORKSPACE file:

`WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "74d544d96f4a5bb630d465ca8bbcfe231e3594e5aae57e1edbf17a6eb3ca2506",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

Replace the path in the bash script using text replacement:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:expand_template.bzl", "expand_template")

expand_template(
    name = "modifiy_use_for_bazel",
    out = "prepared_for_bazel_use.py",
    substitutions = {
        "gen/a.txt": "root/gen/a.txt",
        "gen/a2.txt": "root/gen/a.txt",
    },
    template = "use.py",
)

py_binary(
    name = "use",
    main = "prepared_for_bazel_use.py",
    srcs = ["prepared_for_bazel_use.py"],
    data = [
        "gen/a.txt",
        "gen/a2.txt",
    ],
)
```

You can run now the script via `bazel run root:use`

Note: Tested with Bazel 6.0.0

To make this all a bit more convenient to use you could implement your own rule for it since this seems to be a common problem (e.g. when supporting two build systems at the same time where Bazel is not the primary build system and the other build system can cope with relative path names.)

A similar problem is described here: [Change test execution directory in Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188144/change-test-execution-directory-in-bazel)