# Change test execution directory in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a simple Bazel project layout like this:

```bash
.
├── foo
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── testdata
│   │   └── a.txt
│   └── test.sh
└── WORKSPACE
```

The test checks that `a.txt` exists:

`foo/test.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILE=foo/testdata/a.txt

test -f "$FILE"
```

And it is defined for Bazel like this:

`foo/BUILD.bazel`

```py
sh_test(
  name = "foo",
  size = "small",
  srcs = [ "test.sh" ],
  data = glob([ "testdata/*.txt" ]),
)
```

However, suppose I don't want my test to depend on its location within the workspace:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILE=testdata/a.txt # <-------- Path relative to the package directory

test -f "$FILE"
```

This does not work of course.

```bash
$ bazel test --cache_test_results=no --test_output=streamed //foo

...

//foo:foo        FAILED in 0.0s
```

Is there a way to define my test target in Bazel so that it works, *without modifying my test script*?

---

In case it matters:

```bash
$ bazel --version
bazel 5.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Bazel expects the files to be relative to the `WORKSPACE` file. Therefore, somewhere the path has to be stored. For instance, you can move the path from the `.sh` file to the `BUILD` file:

Add Skylib to your project, i.e. extend your `WORKSPACE` file:

`WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "74d544d96f4a5bb630d465ca8bbcfe231e3594e5aae57e1edbf17a6eb3ca2506",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

Replace the path in the bash script using text replacement:

`foo/BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:expand_template.bzl", "expand_template")
expand_template(
    name = "modifiy_for_bazel",
    out = "test_modfied_for_bazel.sh",
    substitutions = {
        "FILE=testdata/a.txt": "FILE=foo/testdata/a.txt",
    },
    template = "test.sh",
)
sh_test(
    name = "foo",
    size = "small",
    srcs = ["test_modfied_for_bazel.sh"],
    data = glob(["testdata/*.txt"]),
)
```

Now `bazel test --cache_test_results=no --test_output=streamed //foo` works.

A similar problem is described here: [Bazel: Reading a file with relative path to package, not workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536049/bazel-reading-a-file-with-relative-path-to-package-not-workspace/75193658#75193658)